# How can I know why I am blocked from doing questions in the wp development stack?

Tags: discussion

How can I know why I am blocked from doing questions in the wordpress development stack?
When I have a question I make one, what is wrong with that? All the questions are just questions I have? So I do not understand the why and for me makes no sense.
Have read that I will need to improve all my questions that I had made in the past. But I dont see nothing to improve, they are reasonable questions that I had. MAKES NO SENSE!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost 40% of your questions are deleted or closed. You've asked some off-topic questions (syntax errors, WooCommerce, Elementor), and there is rarely any debug information or other visible research effort. You can do better!

The automatic question ban kicks in when too many of your questions are deleted or closed, and when there are too many downvotes from different users. The exact details are a secret.

We have a very [help page about this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) that explains how to fix this issue.

Please do not create new accounts to circumvent the question ban. This would be a serious violation of our rules, and we'd have to block your main account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try to do better. but the questions are closed once the answer has been achieved. Honestly I feel sad for this. Once that I try to answer 10 times more than the doubts I have, and 30% of my questions I had been the one to find the solution that works for me of course. I thank to everyone that I had help me. I had review the 23 questions I posted and I cannot agree with this. happy coding to everyone.

Comment: I am giving this the right answer because I feel that I got the right feedback...